# NSCFConstantString size trying to set an Image

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, nscfstring

I'm making an UITableView with an UIIMage per cell.
To set a different Image per cell I loaded all images in project and made an array with all images `_flagsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"flag_Italia.png", @"flag_USA", nil];`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I wrote

```
UIImageView * flagImageView = (UIImageView *) [self.view viewWithTag:1]; //declaration of UIImageView in cell
UIImage * flagImage = (UIImage *)[_flagsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //read UImage
[flagImageView setImage : flagImage]; //should assign UImage to UIImageView
```

Running it crash with log `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcbdc'`, with signal SIGABRT on third row but I can't understand why, what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array contains strings not images. Also, it looks like you're trying to get the image view from `self.view` when you should getting it from the `cell`. Do like this:

```
UIImageView *flagImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
NSString *imageName = _flagsArray[indexPath.row];
UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
flagImageView.image = flagImage;
```

Or more succinctly:

```
UIImageView *flagImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
flagImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_flagsArray[indexPath.row]];
```